# Session variable still remains null between two different controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables

I have a problem with my MVC project! The goal is to set a session var in order to pass it to all the controllers:
inside my xUserController,

```
            Session["UserId"] = 52;
            Session.Timeout = 30;

            string SessionUserId = ((Session != null) && (Session["UserId"] != null)) ? Session["UserId"].ToString() : "";
```

//SessionUserId ="52"

But within the ChatMessageController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMessageToConference(int? id,ChatMessageModels _model){

        var response = new NzilameetingResponse();
        string SessionUserId = ((Session != null) && (Session["UserId"] != null)) ? Session["UserId"].ToString() : "";
//...

        }
        return Json(response, "text/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

SessionUserId = ""

So, Why this ? How to set the session variable to be global within all my controllers ??

Comment: Session varialbe is global only

Comment: Of course but how do you explain that SessionUserId="" within other controllers ? what do I have to write instead?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: mozilla but the project will target all mayor browsers

Comment: Perhaps this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634419/reusing-session-across-controllers-in-c-sharp-mvc3/10634655#10634655) can help you

Comment: Is that you call Chat controller POST method without much time lag ? As it will be not available after 30 minutes, or the browser is closed...I am just guessing..Can you share more information about time gap etc.. or are you using the same window etc..

Comment: slacker thanks for the link, it has given me the idea (only the idea) that helped me to solve my problem. See my answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is  how I solved the issue

I know this is not the best way to do it but it helped me:

First I have created a base controller as follows

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private static HttpSessionStateBase _mysession;
    internal protected static HttpSessionStateBase MySession {
        get { return _mysession; }
        set { _mysession = value; } 
    }
}
```

then I changed all my controllers' codes in other to let them inherit from the Base Controller class.

Then I overrode the "OnActionExecuting" method as below :

```
public class xUserController : BaseController
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        BaseController.MySession = Session;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(FormCollection form)
    {
        //---KillFormerSession();
        var response = new NzilameetingResponse();
        Session["UserId"] = /*entity.Id_User*/_model.Id_User;
        return Json(response, "text/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Finally, I've changed the way I call session variables.

```
string SessionUserId = ((BaseController.MySession != null) && (BaseController.MySession["UserId"] != null)) ? BaseController.MySession["UserId"].ToString() : "";
```

instead of

```
 string SessionUserId = ((Session != null) && (Session["UserId"] != null)) ? Session["UserId"].ToString() : "";
```

now it works and my session vars can walk across all controllers.

Comment: This is ridiculous. You shouldn't be needing to do this to access your session across controllers. By any chance, are these controllers from MVC and Web.Api?

Comment: this topic is an old version since 2013 please. Many things has changed so far

Answer (score 0):

There can be only two reasons of such behavior: the first one is that your session is over and the second is that you rewrite you session variable from another place in your application.
Wthout any additional code there is nothing to say more.