# Session null issue in mvc when i call a action method from Different Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

[image]I Have two controllers `HomeController` and `MediaController`. 
When I submit the form an action name `EmployeeDetails` is called from `HomeController`.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmployeeDetails(Employee Employee, string Command)
    {
          MediaController MediaController = new Controllers.MediaController();
          Employee.EmployeeModel.newImageId=MediaController.ProcessUploadedImage(FileUpload);     

    }
```

from this method I call a `ProcessUploadedImage`  method which is in `MediaContoller`

```
  public Guid ProcessUploadedImage(FileUpload uploadedFileMeta)
   {
       Session["WorkingImageExtension"]=uploadedFileMeta.Filename.Substring(uploadedFileMeta.Filename.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower();

   }
```

the problem here is that in `ProcessUploadedImage` method I get session value as null, meaning when I check the value of Session in quick watch it displays null.when i hover the cursor on Session it display null in a debug mode.
 So my question is, can I access session during cross controller method access?

Comment: there might be nothing inside the session. try `Session["WorkingImageExtension"]= "some default value"`. And then check if you can access it in another controll. And yes you can access session across controllers. It is only desctroyed when you close the browser

Comment: but here in my case when i hover cursor on session not on Session["WorkingImageExtension"] whole  it give me null and give me a error that object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure it's the session object that is null and not `uploadedFileMeta`? Why don't try the suggestion given by dotnetdreamer and assign a string to `Session["WorkingImageExtension"]` and then step through it.

Comment: you can also try `If` condition. i.e `if(Session["WorkingImageExtension"] !=null) { // session isn't null } else { //session is null }`

Comment: and make sure to debug the code

Comment: yes i am sure uploadedFileMeta is not null. but when i assign any default value to session it fire error.i set the session value in mediacontroller only.

Comment: please see snapshot i attached with post.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple really.

Controllers are not meant to be instantiated by hand in your code. There's a lot of infrastructure code in `ControllerBase` which is meant to be set up by the MVC infrastructure.

Result of that is that the `Session` on your `MediaController` is `null`.

Solution to that is to refactor your code in a way that doesn't introduce coupling between the two controllers the way your current code does.

Comment: so solution is to move my Media Controller code to Home Controller?

Comment: Possibly. Keep your controllers separate

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved a similar issue

I know this is not the best way to do it but it helped me:

First I have created a base controller as follows

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private static HttpSessionStateBase _mysession;
    internal protected static HttpSessionStateBase MySession {
        get { return _mysession; }
        set { _mysession = value; } 
    }
 }
```

then I changed all my controllers' codes in other to let them inherit from the Base Controller class.

Then I overrode the "OnActionExecuting" method as below :

```
public class xUserController : BaseController
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        BaseController.MySession = Session;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(FormCollection form)
    {
        //---KillFormerSession();
        var response = new NzilameetingResponse();
        Session["UserId"] = /*entity.Id_User*/_model.Id_User;
        return Json(response, "text/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

Finally, I've changed the way I call session variables.

string SessionUserId = ((BaseController.MySession != null) &&     (BaseController.MySession["UserId"] != null)) ?     BaseController.MySession["UserId"].ToString() : "";
```

instead of

```
 string SessionUserId = ((Session != null) && (Session["UserId"] != null)) ? Session["UserId"].ToString() : "";
```

now it works and my session vars can walk across all controllers.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211182/session-variable-still-remains-null-between-two-different-controllers)